# java: Cannot run program "D:/AndroidSDK/bin/java" CreateProcess error=2,

Tags: java, android-studio, spotbugs

The full error message is:

*java: Cannot run program "D:/AndroidSDK/bin/java" (in directory "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.1\compile-server" ): CreateProcess error=2, 系统找不到指定的文件。*

I was trying to use spotbugs on project Anki-Android, and when i do spotbug checking on java or kt files under directory "AnkiAndroid" which is the main application folder, it shows this message.

Using Android 9, api = 29. JDK 11. Spotbugs using the plugin version downloaded from intelliJ market place.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIViR.png)

Comment: note that the "D:/AndroidSDK/bin/java" is not a valid path since there only exists AndroidSDK directory but no bin and bin/java in it.

Comment: Did u solved this ?